# Is it possible to change the hover colour in kableExtra?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I regularly use the `kable` and `kableExtra` packages to create beautiful html tables via Rmarkdown.

A client of mine recently requested the hover colour be yellow, rather than the current shade of grey. Does anyone know if this is at all possible?

An reproducible example:

```
require(knitr)
require(kableExtra)
kable(mtcars, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it is. Just add the following lines in your Rmd document:

```
<style>
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover { 
  background-color: #f4f442;
}
</style>
```

Just change the color value `#f4f442` to whatever your client likes.

Comment: Outside. I usually add CSS styles right underneath the YAML header.

Comment: Thank you @Martin Schmelzer!

Comment: How does one add this code to an external style.css file? I tried  simply removing the <style> and </style> wrapper but it gets ignored.

Comment: That should work. The other styles in the external file are working? Try `background-color: #f4f442 !important;`.