# Hovering color of rows in R kable table HTML

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, kableextra

I am producing a html report inside R shiny app using the `rmarkdown::render` function.
I would like to change the hovering color of the rows of the table.
I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418696/is-it-possible-to-change-the-hover-colour-in-kableextra), but it doesn't work for me.

With `tr:hover {background-color: coral;}` only the first row (header) takes the hovering color that I want.
What is weird, is that the `td:hover {background-color: coral;}` works (the hovering color of each cell), but it is not exactly what I would like.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks for the help

```
---
title: "Demand"
author:
  - name: myname
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d/%m/%y')`"
output: 
 html_document
params:
  inputdata: NULL
---

<style>
td:hover {background-color: coral;}
tr:hover {background-color: coral;}
</style>


`r params$inputdata %>%  kbl() %>%  kable_material(c("striped", "hover")) `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kable_material` style is overriding the css selectors. You can use `!important` to make your hovers take precedence:

`````
---
title: "kable_test"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
````

<style>
tr:hover {background-color: coral !important;}
</style>

`r head(mtcars) %>%  kbl() %>%  kable_material(c("striped")) `
`````

The "hover" option isn't then needed.

Comment: argh seems so easy and logical once it is said ... many thanks, it works even without the "!important"

Comment: Yeah, the only advantage of `!important` was if you wanted the striped rows to take on the hover colour too - on mine again the stripes override the hover selector. Glad it works!